# Remove Almost Duplicate Values By Price

Tags: php, sql

I've set up an online store and in the database, there are currently two orders. Despite this, though, when I call the database from PHP (7.0) to appear, with them being in two pairs of almost duplicate, the only differences being the quantity.

I want to group the values by price and delete the one with the lowest quantity of either pair. Also, I am dealing with quantities of 1, in which case both appear the same. I've tried sorting them using the method that was the answer to similar questions to this, but I can't get it to work - it seems to delete just random ones.

SQL
[image]

Query:
`SELECT customers.id AS customer_id, orders.id AS order_id, total_price, tracking, address, email, product_id, quantity, orders.created FROM orders, customers, order_items`

Comment: Whats your current sql query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, you're doing a cartesian product, because you have no criteria on what should be matched between these tables:

```
SELECT
    customers.id AS customer_id
  , orders.id AS order_id
  , total_price
  , tracking
  , address
  , email
  , product_id
  , quantity
  , orders.created
 FROM orders
    , customers
    , order_items
```

You will need to declare how each table relates to each other:

```
SELECT
    customers.id AS customer_id
  , orders.id AS order_id
  , total_price
  , tracking
  , address
  , email
  , product_id
  , quantity
  , orders.created
 FROM    orders o
    JOIN customers c ON (o.customer = c.id)
    JOIN order_items i ON (o.id = i.order_id )
```

Note: I made up some columns that might be sensible names to join the tables to each other. But as you haven't shown us the table definitions that can only be guesswork.